# Permission to see hidden fields

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-fields

There is a node type with hidden fields. Anyone can find nodes of that content type from the search form, and see open information. To see all the fields, users must make a request to the node owner, who decides the users who can see, or not those fields.

Is there any module with this purpose? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Organic groups allows users to be managed and for field visibility to be assigned based on group role.

www.drupal.org/project/og

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [Override node options](https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module.

Comment: Please don't only post link answers. Just put the essential parts of you link in your answer.